# I want to catch an exception and bundle it within my own exception and throw upwards

Tags: c++, exception

I have a class that manages resources. It takes a Loader class that can retrieve the resource from a path. Loader is an abstract base class, so anyone could make a new loader.

If a resource is requested that is not in the cache, the resource manager will request it from the loader. If the loader fails, resource manager throws an exception class I made called LoadingError.

I want the Loader class to throw exceptions when it fails. I can require them to inherit from my own exception base class if necessary.

The problem is, when LoadingError is thrown, I want it to include specific information about why it failed. But I don't know exactly what exceptions may be thrown by the Loader. (The user might, in his catch blocks around the resource manager).

Either I can throw only LoadingError with some general information, or allow a specific exception from Loader come out and not touch it. But I would like to catch the exception and bundle it in my own LoadingError exception, or point to it in LoadingError . But I don't know how long the pointed-to exception will last (concerned about bad pointer).

Which of the three should I do? (And how, for the third one..)

Thanks

Comment: This isn't Visual C++ (.NET), is it?  Because if is, you can use the InnerException property: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.innerexception(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: It's Visual Studio C++ but I'm not using .NET

Comment: Good question. I would be concerned as well, hence I would copy the original (inner) exception.

Comment: just copy the error string to your exception.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about a nested exception?

```
try { /* ... */ }
catch (...)
{
    throw MyException("An error occurred", std::current_exception());
}
```

Just make a suitable class that stores the exception:

```
struct MyException : std::exception
{
    std::string message;
    std::exception_ptr nested_exception;

    MyException(std::string m, std::exception_ptr e)
    : message(std::move(m))
    , nested_exception(std::move(e))
    { }

    // ...
};
```

When the exception is caught, the catcher can rethrow the nested exception:

```
try { /* load resource */ }
catch (MyException & e)
{
    log("Resource loading failed: " + e.what());
    std::rethrow_exception(e.nested_exception);
}
```

In fact, this entire logic is already provided by the standard library via [`std::throw_with_nested`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/error/throw_with_nested).

Comment: There's loads of stuff here I wasn't aware of. Good job.

Comment: Excellent answer! I didn't know about these things! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

When one can enforce use of one's own exception classes throughout the code, the simplest way to do **nested exception** is undoubtedly to just define a custom exception class that contains a **`std::exception_ptr`**, which can be obtained via **`std::current_exception`**, both declared by the **`<exception>`** header.

However, C++11 supports nested exceptions via the **`std::nested_exception`** class, and functions such as **`std::throw_with_nested`**. The `nested_exception` constructor picks up the ? current_exception()`, if any, and stores that as its nested exception. There's no way to specify the nested exception expclitly: it's always the current exception.

This machinery also supports exception propagation through non-exception-aware code such as up through C callbacks, and it supports exceptions (and nested exceptions) of arbitrary classes, not just `std::exception` and derived classes.

So, when e.g. library code uses this functionality, then it's desirable to be able to deal with such **standard nested exceptions**,  and not just one's own custom (simpler to use but less general) scheme.

Sadly, as I'm writing this (Jan 2014) the Visual C++ compiler does not yet support `std::nested_exception`, although it does support much of the rest of the machinery. Happily, it's not difficult to define these things. E.g., googling it, I found working code at [Tomaka-17's blog](http://blog.tomaka17.com/2013/07/c11-nested-exceptions/), and that's the code that I've adapted below  --  `std::nested_exception` **support for Visual C++**:

```
#include <exception>        // std::rethrow_exception

// For Visual C++ define CPPX_NORETURN as "__declspec(noreturn)"
#ifndef CPPX_NORETURN
#   define  CPPX_NORETURN [[noreturn]]
#endif

// Visual C++ 12.0 lacks these things.
// Code adapted from http://blog.tomaka17.com/2013/07/c11-nested-exceptions/.

#if !defined( GOOD_COMPILER )
#include <utility>          // std::forward
#include <type_traits>      // std::remove_reference
namespace std {
    class nested_exception
    {
    private:
        exception_ptr nested;

    public:
        CPPX_NORETURN
        void rethrow_nested() const
        { rethrow_exception(nested); }

        exception_ptr nested_ptr() const { return nested; }

        virtual ~nested_exception() {}
        nested_exception() : nested( current_exception() ) {}
    };

    template< class Type >
    CPPX_NORETURN
    void throw_with_nested( Type&& t )
    {
        typedef remove_reference<Type>::type Pure_type;

        struct Unspecified_mi_type
            : nested_exception
            , Pure_type
        {
            Unspecified_mi_type( Type&& t )
                : Pure_type( forward<Type>( t ) )
            {}
        };

        if (is_base_of<nested_exception, Pure_type>::value)
        {
            throw forward<Type>( t );
        }
        else
        {
            throw Unspecified_mi_type( forward<Type>( t ) );
        }
    }

    template< class X >
    void rethrow_if_nested( X const& x )
    {
        if( auto const ptr = dynamic_cast< nested_exception const* >( &x ) )
        {
            ptr->rethrow_nested();  // It's specified to do this, C++11 §18.8/8.
        }
    }
}
#endif // not GOOD_COMPILER
```

With g++ 4.7.2 it would be more involved to define this stuff, but since g++ 4.8.2 already has it it's not necessary: for g++ just upgrade the compiler if necessary.

Then the next problem is *how to retrieve the nested exception information*.

Essentially that boils down to iteratively **rethrowing** and catching each nested exception, e.g. as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>        // std::runtime_error
#include <stdlib.h>         // EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS

struct Loader { virtual void load() = 0; };

struct Resource_manager
{
    Loader&     loader;

    void foo()
    {
        try
        {
            loader.load();
        }
        catch( ... )
        {
            std::throw_with_nested( std::runtime_error( "Resource_manager::foo failed" ) );
        }
    }

    Resource_manager( Loader& a_loader )
        : loader( a_loader )
    {}
};

int main()
{
    using std::cerr; using std::endl;

    struct Failing_loader
        : Loader
    {
        virtual void load() override { throw std::runtime_error( "Loading failed"); }
    };

    try
    {
        Failing_loader          loader; 
        Resource_manager        rm( loader );

        rm.foo();
        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    }
    catch( ... )
    {
        bool is_cause = false;
        for( auto px = std::current_exception();  px != nullptr;  )
        {
            try
            {
                std::rethrow_exception( px );
            }
            catch( std::exception const& x )
            {
                cerr << "!" << (is_cause? "<because> " : "") << x.what() << endl;
                px = nullptr;
                if( auto pnx = dynamic_cast< std::nested_exception const* >( &x ) )
                {
                    px = pnx->nested_ptr();
                }
            }
            catch( ... )
            {
                cerr << (is_cause? "!<because of an " : "!<") << "unknown failure>" << endl;
                px = nullptr;
            }
            is_cause = true;
        }
    }
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
```

Output:

```
!Resource_manager::foo failed
!<because> Loading failed
```

Disclaimer: I cooked up the above code for this answer, so it's not been extensively tested. But anyway, enjoy!

Comment: Thanks, I could definitely use that (with some testing). I have a question though: isn't it undefined behavior here as you're adding something to the `std` namespace and it doesn't fall into one of [these cases](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/extending_std)?

Comment: @JBL: Yes, formally. It would not be a good idea to apply that workaround to a compiler whose standard library already provides those definitions. That's the purpose of the `GOOD_COMPILER` check: to not include this code where it would not be appropriate. Of course the name should be adjusted to something less likely to collide, and more self-describing. ;-)

Comment: I was looking for [Tomaka's 17](http://blog.tomaka17.com/2013/07/c11-nested-exceptions/) post about exceptions but it is offline. Luckly the code for VS support is posted here.

Comment: @McLeary: By no accident, it's general SO policy to post the code on SO, not off-site, so that it can be found by googlers etc. That said, some nice people keep archives of web pages. And (https://web.archive.org/web/20140901195755/http://blog.tomaka17.com/2013/07/c11-nested-exceptions/) seems to be the latest version of that posting before Tomaka's blog disappeared.