# Does c++ exception support inner exception?

Tags: c++

Since Java and C# 's exception has innerexception which is quite useful when debugging. I am wondering if C++ has this concept as well?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20915882/596781) perhaps. [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22002331/596781) may also be of interest.

Comment: Have a look at [Boost.Exception](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/exception/doc/boost-exception.html), specifically the ability to [transfer arbitrary data to the catch point](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/exception/doc/tutorial_transporting_data.html) (see the [motivation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/exception/doc/motivation.html) section).